# How do I add file input (browse) functionality inside <li> tag in HTML/Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, web-deployment

I am working on getting an `<li>` with an icon and a link tag (`<a>`) to act as browse button, and therefore becoming an input for a file.

What i have originally:

```
<ul>

 <li><a title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Add Video Media"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"> </i></a></li>
<li>  <a title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Add Photos" ><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></a>  </li> 

</ul>
```

and it looks like this:

[Original snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqXVz.png)

I tried inserting `<input type=”file”> </input>` at a couple positions, did not work, instead I got the "Choose file" button on top of my icons, what i ant to do is not displaying the "choose file" button but rather have my icon buttons shown to be it.

Code for failed try(only for photos `<li>` icon):

```
<ul>

 <li><a title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Add Video Media"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"> </i></a></li>
<li>  <a title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Add Photos" ><input id="upload-file" type="file"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></a>  </li> 

</ul>
```

And the result was :

[Failed try snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCDO5.png)

Thanks

Comment: Can I See your whole code (HTML , CSS)?

Comment: You **don't** turn an `<li>` into a button at all. It is neither functionally or semantically correct or even possible!

Comment: @Rob , I rephrased the question, i assume you down-voted my question based on that?

Comment: No but I don't know why I downvoted so I'll remove that.

Comment: thanks, i know my initial phrasing was a little weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#upload-file{
  display: none;
}

label[for=upload-file]{

}
```

```html
<ul>

 <li>
   <a title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Add Video Media">
     <i class="fa fa-video-camera"> </i>
   </a>
 </li>
 <li>  
   <a title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Add Photos" >
     <input id="upload-file" type="file">
     <label for="upload-file">
       <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
     </label>
   </a>  
 </li> 

</ul>
```

Comment: @HMA It's my pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 3):

this is what you need

**html**

```
<input id="upload" type="file"/>
<a href="" id="upload_link">Upload your photo</a>
```

**css**

```
#upload{
   display:none
}
```

**js**

```
$(function(){
    $("#upload_link").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#upload:hidden").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

see [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7aGEv/3/)